# Can't enter text in kivy text input

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, kivy

I can create my text input quite alright, but I can't enter text into it, I can backspace and enter a new line using the enter key but entering a character just doesnt work.
My code below

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6') # replace with your current kivy version !
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.lang import Builder

class Test(TabbedPanel):
   pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

my kv file

```
<Test>:
    do_default_tab: False
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Phone'
        Label:
            text: 'First tab content area'
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'SMS'
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: 'Second tab content area'
            Button:
                text: 'Button that does nothing'
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'USSD'
        TextInput:
            id: _a
            hint_text: 'hello'
            multiline: 'False'
            size: 500,50
            size_hint: None, None
            text:'hello'
```

Comment: @OshasanyaMichael, I have just run your code, and I am able to enter text into the TextInput

Comment: @Imiguelvargasf Well, I dont know why it doesnt work here. My keyboard works for every other thing. I use python3.5 tho. i dnt knw if dat is a problem

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu16.10 x64

Comment: Works on Windows. You might want to [make an issue](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues) in the repo, maybe something broke, but I don't think so. Try reboot and check all deps, then reinstall Kivy, maybe some library got cut off either while/before the compiling of Cython, or before running the code.

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr I m also facing the same issue. i.e, keyword not working for taking inputs. while I work on windows10.

Comment: @Aashish You might want to use at least the latest stable branch or even master branch from the github repository and check whether all required dependencies mentioned in the docs were installed. Inserting works just fine on my various devices.